# What's the exact size of paddingLeft of checkbox?

Tags: android

I wonder what's the exact size of the paddingLeft of checkbox, the padding from the beginning of the layout to the beginning of the checkbox, just like the picture shows.
I guess it's almost 7dp or 8dp.
So where can I get the exact number of it?

Sorry I cannot insert the picture in the body.
The picture is here.

[paddingLeft picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfUwk.png)

Comment: Can you provide your code here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want, is it calculating the distance from the checkbox to the text or what? instead of using padding, you can use:
android: layout_margin: "8dp"
hopefully this can help you

Comment: No, I want to know the size of padding between the beginning of the layout and the beginning of the checkbox.Can you see the picture? I used red to mark the padding I want to know.